# fork()'ing example

Tags: c, linux, fork, system-calls

I am having some trouble understanding the following code. If I run the program with a **single argument (argc of 2)**, the for fork() runs twice and 2 child processes are created. So total processes should be **3**, right? But my Professor said they're supposed to be **4**. I don't understand why.

If one of the child process creates another fork(), why not the second one? What happens when we the program with **two arguments**? Could someone explain step-wise?

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < argc; c++) {
        (void) fork();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In fork() the total process created is = 2^number of fork()  , see the explanation here :  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-multiple-process-using-fork/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone explain step-wise?

**Step 1:** Process 1 calls `fork()` when `c = 0`. Process 2 is created as copy of the current state.

**Step 2:** Process 1 calls `fork()` when `c = 1`. Process 3 is created as copy of the current state.

**Step 3:** Process 2 calls `fork()` when `c = 1`. Process 4 is created as copy of the current state.

**Step 4:** Process 3 starts with `c = 1`, thus the `for` loop terminates after incrementing it to `c = 2`, no further processes created.

**Step 5:** Process 4 starts with `c = 1`, thus the `for` loop terminates after incrementing it to `c = 2`, no further processes created.

Total number of processes: 4.